# angular directive not restricting to A and E

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to do this directive and it does not work as i expected..

```
<nForm nform="tabs"></nForm>

directive('nForm',['$injector', function($injector){
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: "<div class='form-object'></div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           //some more code
        }
      };
])
```

does not work while:

```
<class="nForm" nform="tabs"></nForm>

directive('nForm',['$injector', function($injector){
     return {
        restrict: 'C',
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: "<div class='form-object'></div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           //some more code
        }
      };
])
```

works. what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AngularJs has a strict style to follow while naming the directive and it usage.

Each word with capital letters should be separated with '-'.

for example a directive declaration as below

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
    //...
});
```

should be used as

```
 <my-customer ></my-customer>
```

In your case it should be as

```
<n-form> <n-form>
```

The reasoning for this transformation is that while JavaScript is case sensitive, HTML is not. So angular internally renames the markup references so that the conventions in each environment are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

You shall write like this:

```
<class="nForm" n-form="tabs"></nForm>
```

Directive name "nForm" means that in html it should be written like "n-form" (because of big F)